# Ruby on rails application shows files index instead of the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I would like to deploy a Ruby on Rails application on the web, and for that matter I have used/deployed the following tools:

1. Capistrano, to deploy the app files to the target location
2. The Phusion Passenger module for Apache

I have enabled the Passenger module through `sudo a2enmod passenger`. I have also installed the passenger gem through the gem installer, and added it to the Gemfile of my rails app.
I have then created an Apache virtual host for the app 'myapp'.

**myapp.conf**

```
  Alias /myapp /var/www/myapp/current/public
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/current/public
    SetEnv SECRET_KEY_BASE 592da***************************************
   <Directory /var/www/myapp/current/public>
     PassengerEnabled on
     PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
     PassengerAppRoot /var/www/myapp/current
     PassengerAppType rack
     PassengerStartupFile config.ru
     Allow from all
     Options -MultiViews
     Require all granted
   </Directory>    
 </VirtualHost>
```

The virtual host work, but when I access the URL in a web browser, it shows the files index in /var/www/myapp/current/public instead of the actual app. The reason for this seems to be that passenger is not started, but I can't figure out why. I have tried to tweak the myapp.conf file to help apache and passenger detect the app, but without success.

Could anyone help me fix this? Thanks in advance.

Additional info: the app is deployed on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie as OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .This  is  for sub uri deployment.Error is because PassengerRuby path has not been mentioned. Also go through this link
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/.

```
Alias /myapp /var/www/myapp/current/public
 <VirtualHost *:80>
SetEnv SECRET_KEY_BASE 592da***************************************
PassengerRuby /path-to-ruby    /* replace this with your ruby path
 <Location /myapp>
    PassengerBaseURI /myapp
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/myapp/current
    PassengerEnabled on
 </Location>

 <Directory /var/www/myapp/current/public>
   Allow from all
   Options -MultiViews
   Require all granted
 </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used your code and populated the PassengerRuby with the ruby path indicated by the command `passenger-config about ruby-command`. Unfortunately, it did not solve the issue; when reloading apache, I still get the files index and not the app when I connect to the URL.